# Semantic UI Icons-font not loading

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, semantic-ui

I am building a website using the Semantic UI CSS framework, and now I want to use some of its icons.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h1>Title<i class="lab icon"></i></h1>
```

I have linked the semantic.css, but I assume I need to do something else too to get the icons working? I tried linking this too:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Digging in the semantic CSS file reveals that the fonts need to be located here (relative to your semantic.css): `themes/default/assets/fonts/`

Source:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/dist/semantic.css#L5466-5467

Comment: Not exactly. Its parallel to your semantic.min.css. Otherwise you can change font folder path via a external stylesheet as well.

Comment: Updated the link and the location (they changed), thanks

Comment: According to my situation, I have to put `theme` folder into the `css` folder. An easy way to detect the path: open website with Chrome, inspect element - Network, find the unloaded font url.

Comment: If this isn't an option, are we really meant to find/replace that string?

Comment: @DitmarWendt Yes, unless you want to create some kind of URL redirect depending on how much control you have over the web server.

Answer (score 13):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/css/semantic.min.css'>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/icon.min.css'>
  
  
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Icon Example</h1>
  <a class="item"><i class="alarm icon"></i>Notifications</a>
  <a class="item"><i class="mail outline icon"></i>Messages</a>

</body>

</html>
```

you can try taking a look at the above snippet. You may also use the  below link for other similar issues:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui

Comment: Updating your example to the `2.2.13` version shows more icons like the id card one.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use font-awesome of any other library 
try cdn first Official [icon.min.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui)

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/components/icon.min.css'>
```

somethimes this doesn't work so what you can do is
go [semantic-ui official page](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html)
download semantic ui zip folder and extract 
in component folder you can find **icon.min.css**

include that file in **index.html**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="icon.min.css">
```

try to display those icon [Official docs](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html#/definition)

```
<i class="disabled users icon"></i>
```

*ENJOY*

Answer (score 0):

My solution was pretty simple (once I worked it out). I had edited `themes.config` to use my new (yet to be built) theme. As you know it falls back to `default`so everything seemed to work OK.

```
/* Elements */
:
@flag       : 'supernewtheme';
@header     : 'supernewtheme';
@icon       : 'supernewtheme';
@image      : 'supernewtheme';
@input      : 'supernewtheme';
:
```

Even though the console showed the Icons font loading (no 404), iti didn't work. I also checked the font was in my `build` folder in the correct place, it was.

Changing the theme back to `default` for `@icon` did the trick:

```
@icon       : 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone is using electron or any other JavaScript framework.
This might work for you.
Icon's in electron after setting up semantic properly were not showing. The error is not in semantic neither loading. Error is with Photon and semantic combination. I used photon with semantic to make my UI look great.
Basic solution I opted is in reference to [this](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4993) official error reporting. 
Also in my UI icon wasn't appearing for a drop-down so I used console to solve like

```
.myclass .icon:before, .myclass.icon-before {
    font-family: 'dropdown';
}
```

Hope it helps.